# Storing double values in binary file and reading it

Tags: c#, binary, hex

I need to store double values in binary files and read them. My data is stored in an array. I have tried the following code but apparently I am storing more values than the array size and I am reading totally wrong data. Like if I am storing 0.26 from array[0], I can see the very few first values in the binary file to be A4 70 3D... I don't get how it is converting 0.26 to these values and on what basis.

This code is for writing to binary file:

```
  double [] DataCollection_array = new double[10000];

  public void store_data()
   {
    Binary_filename = folder_path + "\\" + "Binary1.bin";
    stream = new FileStream(folder_path + "\\" + "Binary1.bin", FileMode.Create);
    binary_writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
    writetoBinary(DataCollection_array.size);
   }


  public void writetoBinary(int size)
        {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    binary_writer.Write(DataCollection_array[i]);
                }
         }
```

This code for reading the double values from a folder that contains binary files:

```
  int bytes_counter1 = 0;
  Channels = new List<double>[File_size];

  public void read_data ()
  {
  path2 = Directory2.folder_path + "\\" + "Binary" + file_number + ".bin";
  file_stream = new FileStream(path2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  using (reader = new BinaryReader(file_stream))
         {
          if (bytes_counter1 < reader.BaseStream.Length)
             {
             reader.BaseStream.Seek((count + offset1), SeekOrigin.Begin);
             Channels.Add((double)reader.ReadByte());
             bytes_counter1++;

             }
          }
     }
```

Comment: You are writing 8 bytes (the size of a double) but only reading back 1 byte.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that the file size is actually 8 times the array size. How can I convert the 8 bytes back to double?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing doubles:

```
binary_writer.Write(DataCollection_array[i]);
```

But you are only reading bytes:

```
Channels.Add((double)reader.ReadByte()); // Read one byte
```

Change it to:

```
Channels.Add(reader.ReadDouble()); // Read one double
```

Comment: My rule of thumb is, if you have to cast something, you are probably doing it wrong.  Remember this: every cast, kills a kitten.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.